# Adding audio record feature in the video playing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, flash, mediaelement.js

I am using **Mediaelementjs** to play the video and flash to record the video.
Is there a way to trigger flash event using javascript?

> An example would be to trigger an event which allows access to
>   microphone and start recording the audio.

I want to auto trigger audio record of flash once the video stops playing.

```
$(function() {
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function(player, node) {
            player.addEventListener(
                'ended',
                function(e) {
                    //alert('the player has ended playing.');
                    $(
                        '#<%= submit_hidden.ClientID %>'
                    ).click();
                    return false;
                });
        }
    });
 });
```

Right now, what i am doing is, after the **video ends**, trigger a **click event** which prompts the user to allow access to microphone and camera, but i can't seem to simulate the click of the allow access and start recording the audio which later has to be **concatenated** to the video itself.

All i want is to start recording an audio after the video ends, if not with **`Flash`** then any other. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alex, Just want to understand correctly, so the video stops playing but the audio continues playing saved somewhere then on record stop both video and audio continue in sync from where the audio is stopped recording ?   Not sure also what you mean by 'and get the whole thing as a whole video file'

Comment: No, when we pause the video, it gives the feature of recording audio, when we stop recording audio it gets concatenated inbetween the video, the rest of the video starts playing. Then the whole video file will be replaced by new whereby, the audio lies within that video.

Comment: Can you provide some background as to what code you are using to play/record the video?

Comment: please check my edited question.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem, but: Create a javascipt eventhandler for the pauze event of the video, then invoke your record button? I can post some code as a answer if you like.

Comment: That is not difficult, the difficult part is having to concat the video before the pause and after the pause whereby the audio is in between :/ thank you for your positive response though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

when you want to continue the video
The Request data of the client  must contain where the video size he had play

Then you can figure out the right size of the video on the server and response it from the size.